# Highlighting Changes in Excel Based on Multiple Matching Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to highlight changes that are made to a group of data in an Excel spreadsheet.  The data looks like this:

`A         B
Joe     Burger
Joe     Burger
Sue     Nuggets
Sue     Fries
Sue     Nuggets`

The data is sorted by column A, so all groups are adjacent to each other.

I would like to set up a mechanism that highlights all of Sue's values in column B, triggered off the fact that all of her corresponding entries in column B do not match each other.  I would not want Joe's values to be highlighted because they all match each other.

Comment: Create a [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule based upon the following formula: `=COUNTIFS($A:$A, "sue", $B:$B, $B1)=1` or if column A is not to be exclusively **sue** then `=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A1, $B:$B, $B1)=1`.

Comment: That only highlights the "Fries" value, and doesn't work at all if there are multiple instances of both "Nuggets" and "Fries" for the value "Sue."  I'm trying to highlight the whole "Sue" group if the values in B don't all match each other.  Sorry if I'm being unclear, it's a difficult problem to describe!

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned whether column A is sorted (your example is) but this should work even if not, but may require refreshing a PivotTable if the entries in ColumnsA:B increase over time, and double clicking a cell in ColumnC even if only new names are added.

Construct a PivotTable with `A` for ROWS and `B` for Columns. In C3 and copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTA(E3:XFD3)
```

Then apply a Conditional Formatting rule to ColumnA of:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,D:D,0))>1
```

[image: SO32489482 example]

Comment: This is a great idea, but I need it to calculate automatically without any user input.  Coworkers are going into this sheet and changing stuff, and there are a few columns that need to all have the same info per group in column A, so I need something that highlights groups that don't match in real time.  I'm starting to think maybe an array formula might work.  If not that, then VBA maybe?

Comment: Yeah sorry about not being more explicit with my requirements -- I'm not too experienced communicating on technical problems like this.  I appreciate your help though, both with your answer and with etiquette.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've got it figured out, and I'm ashamed to say I think I was outsmarting myself.  @Jeeped was close with the countifs . . . I ended up adding two columns with one countif each.  For reference, this is what would go in cell C1 in my example above:

`=countif($A$1:$A$5,"="&A1)`

This would go in D1:

`=countif($B$1:$B$5,"="&B1)`

Then, add a conditional formatting formula that compares the two and formats if they don't match.  The formula would look like this:

`=C2<>D2`

This highlights all of the rows with the value Sue, and automatically removes formatting if the values in column B are changed so that they all match.

Thanks for your help with this, people!